# PHP color intensity detection

Tags: php

How can I detect intensity of this hex color: `#000000`? I can use that method for this code.
For example if background color is black, text-color must be set to `#FFFFFF` (white). I'm using this snippet for generating random color:

```
$random_color = '#'.base_convert(rand(0, 16777215), 10, 16);
```

Comment: What do you men by intensity, and what are you trying to achieve? Do you want the inverse of the randomly generated color?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to automatically pick a color that will be easily readable on the background based on the BGcolor of the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're couple of valid approaches but the simpliest is to convert your color to grayscale and then check if result value is in upper half or lower. If in upper, then it's light color and you should use i.e. black as text color, if in lower, then it's dark, so white will work best. Something like this:

```
function getReadableTextColor( $backgroundColor ) {
    $R = ($backgroundColor >> 16 ) & 0x000000ff;
    $G = ($backgroundColor >>  8 ) & 0x000000ff;
    $B = ($backgroundColor       ) & 0x000000ff;

    // grayscale: 0.3RED + 0.59GREEN + 0.11Blue
    $K = (($R * 0.3) + ($G * 0.59) + ($B * 0.11));

    // black fg color for light background, white for dark ones
    return ( $K > 128 ) ? 0x000000 : 0xffffff;
}
```

then use like this

```
$bgColor = rand(0, 16777215);
$bgcolorHTML = '#' . base_convert($bgColor, 10, 16);
$fgColor = getReadableTextColor( $bgColor );
$fgColorHtml = '#' . base_convert($fgColor, 10, 16);
```

Comment: thanks, now how to use that for this code:echo "<span style='background-color:{$fgColor}'>salam</span>";

Answer (score -1):

I think, You need to calculate the negative color for good readability. Try this function:

```
<?php 
    function NegativeColor($color)
    {
        $r = substr($color, 0, 2);
        $g = substr($color, 2, 2);
        $b = substr($color, 4, 2);

        //Invert colors, (255  - colVal)
        $r = 0xff-hexdec($r);
        $g = 0xff-hexdec($g);
        $b = 0xff-hexdec($b);

        return str_pad(dechex($r),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT)
               .str_pad(dechex($g),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT)
               .str_pad(dechex($b),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }   
    var_dump(NegativeColor('000000'));
    //output : string(6) "ffffff" 
?>
```